# Defining physicsbody for a curved object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I define the physics body of an curved or not rectangle object

I know for a rectangle I use ( rectangle of : width,height)

And for a circle I use (circle of radius: )

But how can I do this for a different object like this one

[image]

Comment: You can use `UIBezierpath` to define a path, which can be converted into a `physicsBody` object.

Comment: Can you show me the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **CGPath** like this:

```swift
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), radius: 50, startAngle: 20, endAngle: 60, clockwise: true)
node?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: path)
```

You can show the bodies of **SKView** with:

```swift
view.showsPhysics = true
```

[image]

The complete example are here: [GameScene.swift](https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/CurvedPhysicsBody/CurvedPhysicsBody/GameScene.swift)

Comment: Can you please implement it on this project

Comment: on physics body p1

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nch0xjxnammop11/AADB_TG1BghZA_wiZbCZtGjba?dl=0