# How to create a SKPhysicsBody in a shape of a parabola?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I need to create a SKSpriteNode or a SKShapeNode such that it would look like the image below. I can figure out how to use a texture to get the shape of the line but I can't seem to find a way to make the physics body. It needs to be made out of two horizontal lines which can change their y position and the middle parabola-like shape joins the other two lines with a specified maximum point (the maximum would hopefully be a variable). [image: The shape -]

(Note:- the blue and green lines are just to highlight that the image is compromised of three objects)
Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Use a UIBezierPath or NSBezierPath to make a shape object and read it with SKShapeNode.

Comment: @ElTomato If you dont mind could you link me to a good reference, the docs are hard to understand

Comment: What's stopping you from running a search with `SKShapeNode` and `UIBezierPath` or `NSBezierPath`?

Comment: Point taken, sorry, and Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this question is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145181/defining-physicsbody-for-a-curved-object/65238553#65238553

Comment: @Maetschl, sort of, but I dont want it to be circular, but rather parabolic, which is why I had to use a UIBezierCurve. Thanks for the help though!